Format smallest value in range of same category in Excel
I have a table with the unit prices of various articles (products) of various stores. I want to highlight the smallest value of a given product across all stores. I have already achieved this, using conditional formatting with the custom formula =AND(B2=MIN($B2:$D2), B2 <> "") in the range =$B$2:$D$4 for the following Excel spreadsheet:

As you can see, it works. But now I have a new problem. I want to add a column for the category of the product, and highlight the cheapest product across all stores and across the category. In this way, I can know, for example, the cheapest brand of cheese in all stores. The following table shows how I'd like it to behave:

I tried =AND(A2=$A$2:$A$7, C2=MIN($C2:$E2), C2 <> "") in the range =$C$2:$E$7, but it doesn't work.
Markdown table



Category
Article
Store 1
Store 2
Store 3




Cat 1
Product 1
$30.00
$35.00
$27.00


Cat 1
Product 2
$29.00
$24.00
$25.00


Cat 1
Product 3
$32.00
$33.00
$35.00


Cat 2
Product A
$4.00
$4.30
$4.50


Cat 2
Product B
$5.00
$5.50
$4.50


Cat 2
Product C
$3.50
$4.00
$3.75




You can apply the following conditional formatting rule to C2:E7:
=C2=MIN(FILTER($C$2:$E$7,$A$2:$A$7=$A2))


